# How to set a max height for UIImageView regardless of final Image size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, size

I have an issue where I have a UIImageView with mode as "Aspect Fill".  I have set dimensions for my UIImageView, but I've noticed at runtime, the height of the UIImageView tends to change based on the final image rendered after it's been filled.

Is there a way to set a max height for the UIImageView regardless of the height of the content that fills it.  Basically what I want is something similar to the kind of functionality we have in CSS whereby I can perform an "overflow: hidden" type of command, so that anything beyond the size of the UIImageView is hidden/ignored.

Is there a way to accomplish this in iOS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there are two possible causes here:

a) The UIImageView might be growing because of the auto-layout constraints applied to it: If you are using auto-layout just set a constraint to the UIImageView with a maximum (or fixed) height.

[image]

b) The UIImageView might not be growing at all but you are seeing the "excess" of the image because the view is not clipping it. Just set the clipsToBounds to true either on Interface Builder or from your code.

Comment: I'll give this a shot sometime later and report back the results.  You bring up a good point, I need to determine first if the ImageView is actually growing or I am just seeing the excess of the image overflow out of the ImageView

Comment: Boom!  This fixed it @Reflejo.  I set the UIImageView.clipToBounds to TRUE and this is doing exactly what I want now, while maintaining Aspect Ratio as well as filling the entire UIImageView.  Thank you!

Comment: oh thanks for clipsToBounds! I already thought that I went crazy

Answer (score 2):

Use "Scale to Fill", it will scale the image according to the UIImageView size.

"Aspect Fill" will not shrink the UIImageView, but will only print on a part of it.

Comment: Hmm...I don't see an "Aspect Scale" option.  I only see, Scale To Fill, Aspect Fill, Aspect Fit etc....?

Comment: Sorry "Scale to Fill", I didn't have the exact option on the top of my head... Answer is edited.

Comment: I tried that one, the problem with that behaviour is that it is not maintaining the Aspect Ratio of the Image.  I still want the Aspect Ratio maintained, while filling the entire ImageView and whatever goes outside the boundaries can be hidden.

Comment: So basically, you want an "Aspect Fill" behavior with a scale ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. i had **four views**, the **top one** had an **image**, the others were *three buttons*. I put the **three buttons** in one stack view. and put the **image** in another **stack view**. And all i had to do was set the **aspect ratio** to what i wanted and the magic was done. and, this was, it was also easy to adapt to small screens or Portrait and Lanscape mode using *size-classes* or *variations*.